# php login script not working redirecting to blank page

Tags: php

Just Trying hands in PHP copyied one Login Script from web.But it is going to logincheck.php page , which is shown blank.Here is full script

login.html

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
<meta name="author" content="" />

<title>Simple login</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="login">
<h2>Simple login with PHP MYSQL</h2>
<form action="logincheck.php" method="post">
<p> Username <label><input type="text" name="uname" /></label></p>
    <p> Password <label><input type="password" name="passwd" /></label></p>
<label><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" /></label>
</form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

logincheck.php

```
<?php

/**
* @author 
* @copyright 2013
*/

$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","")or die("Cannot connect to databases!");
mysql_select_db("fakebook",$con);

$u=$_POST['uname'];
$p=md5($_POST['passwd']);
$query=mysql_query("
     select * from users where username='$u' and password='$p'
    ");
$row=mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($row == 1)
{
    session_start();
    $a=mysql_fetch_array($query);
    $_SESSION['user']=$a['username'];
    header("location: home.php");
}
else
{
    header("location: login.html");
}

?>
```

home.php

```
<?php

/**
* @author 
* @copyright 2013
*/



session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['user'])){
    echo "Welcome,".$_SESSION['user']."<br />
                [ <a href=\"logout.php\">Logout</a> ]";
}else{
    echo "You are not authorized into this page!";
}
?>
```

logout.php

```
<?php

/**
* @author 
* @copyright 2013
*/

session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['user'])){
    session_destroy();
    header("location: login.html");
}
else{
    header("location: login.html");
}

?>
```

Database name : fakebook,table name : users

Comment: what happens? Any errors?

Comment: fakebook! hahaha nice one =)

Comment: Is your php error reporting on?

Comment: The author of this script should be killed. Try another script, this one have many security issues!!

Comment: @Robert ,john No error, bur redirecting to checklogin.php page and its blank

Comment: try to echo something on the checklogin.php page. ie `echo "here";` and check whether it is displayed in browser

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown :  :P, I am new to it and I found it really simple so picked it.Can u provide with something good and easy.

Comment: Your form action is logincheck.php where as you posted code for checklogin.php ...please check the names on both the places.

Comment: @user162098 if this is for training, it's ok. Don't ever use this on a real page.

Comment: ya just for training....@RajeevRanjan ya mistaken here

Answer (score 0):

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php
header('Location: http://www.example.com/'); it's capital L not l . May be this problem. And this script is not good/secure (no escape string, etc). You are also using mysql not mysqli,

Comment: Thank I have changed it to L.But still not working.And just strarting from baic so not included protections

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should place this code at the top of your checklogin.php page to see if there is any error:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

After having done that check what is the error if there is one.

Also I notice that in your HTML form it is redirecting to logincheck.php but you named the file checklogin.php

Comment: Nice notice, but I mistaken here.No effect after putting that code.

Answer (score 0):

Your login form is directing to `logincheck.php`. Shouldn't it be directing to `checklogin.php`?

If so, changed this:

```
<form action="logincheck.php" method="post">
```

To this:

```
<form action="checklogin.php" method="post">
```

Comment: Thanks ...Yea I have edited here...It was alright their in the code..But that's not the problem ,its something else

Comment: Could I see the demo, so I can try and see where it is going wrong?

Also I thought that would have fixed it because the page was just blank.

Comment: what you mean by "demo".You want printscreen?

Comment: A link to test the scripts

Comment: Sorry but I can't understand you.I set up a wamp server and using phpdesigner.You can use above given script on your own system with database name fakebook and table name users

Comment: Moreover I have taken script from here http://www.sharingsession.com/simple-login-php-mysql